# Compare timestamp with datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have one timestamp from a dataframe and a datetime object, I want to compare them to do a select in a dataframe. My data are as followed:

```
print(type(datetime.datetime.now()))
<class 'datetime.datetime'>

print(type((df.created_at[0])))
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

How can I select specific rows within that dataframe with the datetime object? as follow:

```
df[df.created > datetime.datetime.now()]
```

But it returns me the following error message: `TypeError: Cannot compare tz-naive and tz-aware datetime-like objects`, any idea on how to solve that? thanks!

Comment: since this is pandas-specific, you can use the pandas-equivalent `pd.Timestamp('now', tz=df.created_at[0].tzinfo)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timestamp is a timezone-aware object, while the datetime object you get from `datetime.datetime.now()` is timezone-naive since you don't specify otherwise, hence the error. You should convert so that they're either both timezone-aware or both timezone-naive.

For example, you can call `datetime.datetime.now()` like this to make it timezone-aware (passing timezone info from timestamp object as an argument):

```
datetime.datetime.now(df.created_at[0].tzinfo)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[df.created.to_pydatetime() > datetime.datetime.now()]
```

Should work https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.Timestamp.to_pydatetime.html#pandas.Timestamp.to_pydatetime